# Are Statuses in Cognito Forms Editable?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to change the status options that can be assigned to entries in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com)?

Currently the options are Incomplete, Submitted, Reviewed and Complete.  I would like to change these to something that better meets my workflow needs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit the built in entry statuses in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

However, you can definitely add your own Status field to your form, and mark the field as Show This Field - Internally so it only appears for your internal users and not the person filling out the form.

Also, this is part of our proposed Entry Workflow enhancements, so if this interests you, please comment and upvote this feature on our Idea Board!

https://trello.com/c/AtfEqasG/35-entry-workflow-management